# odbc_fetch_array no funciona no reconoce el alias dado en la consulta SQL, php 5.6 y sql server 20005

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

Básicamente, necesito obtener algunos datos de un SQL Server 2005, usando PHP.

Anteriormente usábamos las funciones **mssql_***, sin embargo, debido a varios problemas con el servidor, ahora sólo podemos usar las funciones **odbc_***.

La tabla tiene varias columnas cuyos nombres tienen espacios en ellas, y antes de que se sugiera ... no, no puedo cambiarlas, ya que esta es una pieza de software totalmente separada en otro idioma y la rompería, simplemente estoy eliminando estadísticas de eso

En cualquier caso, anteriormente había accedido a estas columnas poniendo sus nombres entre corchetes, por ejemplo, [nombre de columna] y funcionó bien en las funciones **mssql_***, sin embargo, cuando hago esto:

```
$sql = "select [primer nombre] as primerNombre from bksb_Assessments";
$result = odbc_exec($db, $sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Imprime los resultados como:

> 'primer nombre' => cadena 'Juan' (longitud = 25)

Entonces, como puede ver, está ignorando totalmente el alias que le he dado y aún así lo llama [**primer nombre**].

Pero si ejecuto exactamente lo mismo en SQL Server Management Studio Express, funciona bien y usa el alias.

He intentado varias combinaciones diferentes, como citar el alias, citar la columna, diferentes corchetes, etc. Pero no he tenido suerte hasta ahora.

Esto no es un gran problema, ya que puedo cambiar lo que mi script usa para buscar **nombre de evaluación** en la matriz de resultados en lugar del alias, pero es un poco molesto que no haya podido averiguar por qué sucedió esto.

Esto es una copia de alguien que le paso lo mismo, pero en su fila no hay solución por eso lo volví a crear.

Comment: Yo lo haría con un foreach. Mira esta respuesta de una consulta similar, puede que te sirva. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282418/odbc-while-and-foreach-loop-outputs-2-results-in-php

Comment: Esta pregunte es una copia textual de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200072/73749). Aunque esto es valido, **siempre** hay que aclarar que es una copia. Tambien, para estos casos, hay que poner una referencia a la original, y tambien dar una respuesta valida.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  estas es una copia textual de una pregunta en ingles, no tiene las referencias a la misma y el usuario tampoco se tomo el tiempo en generar unar respuesta. Cuando todo ello ocurra, se podra volver a abrir.

Comment: Fue la versión del freetds la cambien y funcionó sin problema. https://www.freetds.org/ Yo use la https://www.freetds.org/files/old/ 0.64